# How to execute a query string in MonetDB

Tags: exec, execute, monetdb

I'm attempting to declare a query string to execute in MonetDB.  The documentation is not clear if this is possible, but other engines allow this functionality (such as MySQL and MS SQL Sever).  Trying the following

```
execute 'select * from tables';
```

fails with the message

```
Error: syntax error, unexpected STRING, expecting IDENT or sqlINT
```

The reason behind this is that I need to declare a variable schema name, such that I can execute a query in the following way:

```
declare s varchar(32);
set s = 'the_schema';
execute 'select * from ' || the_schema || '.the_table';
```

Please let me know if this is even possible in MonetDB or if you have some tips about that.  I tried with a prepared statement, as given in MonetDB's documentation -- but the following code cannot execute

```
prepare 'select * from ' || the_schema || '.the_table';
```

because `prepare` expects an actual query, not a string.

**Edit**

I'd like to achieve this with only SQL stored functions.  The client I have has to execute the SQL functions directly, and there's no intermediate Java/PHP/etc scripts to build the SQL on the fly before they're being sent to MonetDB server.  Thus, I should create a function like so:

```
create function getData( dataSchema varchar(32) )
returns bigint
begin
    declare query varchar(128);
    set query = 'select count(*) from ' || dataSchema || '.the_table';
    return( execute query );
end;
```

My function is more complicated than this, with other tables and even functions.  The issue is that functions belong to one schema, and data tables belong to another schema, which is not known in 'compile' time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, MonetDB does not support this.

If the only varying parts of the constructed query are values, you could try PREPARE:

```
sql>PREPARE SELECT * FROM foo WHERE id = ?;
execute prepared statement using: EXEC 13(...)
sql>EXEC 13(22);
```

But it is not possible to for example write `FROM ?`.  For that kind of thing, the only alternative is to do the string concatenation client side.

Comment: Say I can build that query string in the client side -- what's the statement to execute it? `execute query_string`?  The reason for doing this is that I have SQL functions to manipulate data in one schema, and the actual data in a different schema whose name is not known in run time (i.e. depends on the installation and end username).

Comment: I'm afraid it's just not possible to execute a query string, only a query.

Answer (score 2):

This should be considered a hack, but the ability of python UDFs to execute SQL queries makes this possible, via the predefined `_conn` handler:

```
create or replace function tableLen( schema string, name string )
returns bigint
language python {
    query = 'select count(*) as c from ' + schema + '.' + name + ';'
    result = _conn.execute(query)
    return result['c']
};
```

Then

```
sql>select tableLen('sys','tables');
+------+
| L2   |
+======+
|  101 |
+------+
1 tuple (12.535ms)
```

More in general, using this trick you may be tempted to have a similar function that you can use this way for any query:

```
sql> select myExecute('SELECT ..... ');
```

Mind that this will *not* be possible, because you need to define the exact return type for that function, which of course will not match a generic query.