# How to pass table as a input parameter in function?

Tags: monetdb

Is it possible to pass table as input parameter in Monetdb function/procedure?
I tried prepare statement but was not able to get it working.
Also it would be nice to get statementid returned directly by 'prepare' statement rather then query sys.prepared_statements

Comment: You can fire two new "enhancement" issues here: https://github.com/MonetDB/MonetDB/issues?  And ask all your friends to help increase their priorities.

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot pass (table) identifiers to functions/procedures.
You could use [this trick](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50469269/1248563), but I wouldn't recommend it for production use.